# Post to different domain fails sporadically

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm having an issue when "Post"ing to a different site as part of a session transfer to a company I'm working with. They have asked us to navigate to their site via means of a "Post" request with the session token in the query string (Yes, there's no body in the request).

This is the code I'm using for the Post request:

```
navigateByPost = function(path, parameters)
{
    var form = $('<form />');

    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("action", path);

    parameters && $.each(parameters, function (key, value)
    {
        var field = $('<input />');

        field.attr("type", "hidden");
        field.attr("name", key);
        field.attr("value", value);

        form.append(field);
    });

    $(document.body).append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

I'm calling it thusly:

```
navigateByPost('http://other.site/login/?parameter1=sessiontokenhere');
```

Most of the time, this works correctly, but sometimes, at completely random intervals, I'm seeing the request being canceled, and the navigation never happens. This is what I'm seeing in the chrome dev tools when the navigation fails:

[image: Screenshot of the request failure from the Chrome dev tools]

I've checked in Firefox and the problem doesn't seem to occur, so I'm at a loss as to what the actual problem is. I know it can't be a problem at the other parties end, as there's no way it can get there and be rejected in a single millisecond. It must be something in the browser, but I've no idea.

Please help me out guys, I'm running out of desk to bang my head on!

Comment: You are missing to include the "path" variable in your call to navigateByPost(); or are there some magic occuring that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Are posting the data between secured and unsecured? ie., http/https?!

Comment: @limelights I've included the path in the call, but there are no parameters to send with the post request, hence why the 2nd parameter is empty.

Comment: @devsathish The connections are currently http » http, but they will be https » https in the future providing we can get this to work.

Comment: @brins0 but if the parameters are empty in some cases wouldnt that cause the form to be without fields?

Comment: @limelights yes, but the form does get posted correctly 4 out of 5 times on average, even with no form elements. I don't believe it's to do with the form being empty unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the code shown above does actually function correctly. I've found that the link which had the code attached to it is what was actually causing the problem.

Before, I was was getting the element like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.sessiontransfer", function(e) {
    e.PreventDefault();
    doSessionTransfer();
    return false;
});
```

so that if any additional links were added to the page, they would pick up this functionality. I've found that this does not work 100% of the time, occasionally producing the error I pasted above in the screenshot. I've since changed this to the following;

```
$("a.sessiontransfer").off().on("click", function(e) {
    e.PreventDefault();
    doSessionTransfer();
    return false;
});
```

I've yet to have this fail on any device I've tried it on, but it has the unfortunate side effect that if I add any links to the page, I'll have to re-call this functionality to re-hook all the elements, making sure to remove existing clicks first.

I hope this will help save someone a couple of days of investigation and save a few desks in the process!